# heat air with nichrome wire

Tags: power-supply, transformer, control

108 rows of grapevines, each row 650 feet long.  Suspend a nichrome enameled wire along each row in order to raise the temperature of the air within 18 inches of the wire 6 degrees Fahrenheit.  What kind of transformers and controllers?  220 V AC is all that is available.  No three phase.

Comment: Do you expect the temperature of the air to be raised a _minimum_ of 6 degrees within a cylinder of air 18 inches in diameter, or is the temperature raised _exactly_ 6 degrees uniformly within that cylinder? What is the ambient temperature? Is there any wind?

Comment: Just off the top of my head seems like the power required would be very expensive vs. the benefit.  In most grape-growing regions they use large fans to circulate the air near the vines, which prevents frost from forming on the leaves.  In areas too cold for that they plant hybrid grapes that are more tolerant to the cold.  I'm not aware of anyone using electrical heating to grow grapes.

Comment: Air volume x thermal capacity of air x temp rise x airchanges/hour = power required. Rough calculations suggests it will be ~= vast. Think of the output of an eg 1 kW fan heater. How much vine length would you expect it could maintain at 6F rise. Is there a shroud or is this open air? This sounds like it would take many 10's to probably 100's of kW to achieve - with answer VERY dependant on how it is enclosed - if at all.

Comment: Looks like spring frost is coming and you are in deep dodo.  If night frost, in clear sky, use sprinkler with warm water.  If cold wind, use poly tents to block wind and cover if possible. Warm water sprinkler can add heat to prevent freezing with just a mist in high RH% but if low RH can create wind chill, so no wind with tent. Check Dew point temp with remote sensors.

Comment: This past Monday am the temperature was 26 degrees F for six hours, killing all new growth and ruining chance of harvest this year.  I have fairly cheap electricity at 7 cents per KWH available.  This system would have low initial capitilization costs compared to sprinklers or fans.  They report fans will only work for about three degrees; we are talking about 6 degrees at the edge of the air cylinder.  This system would only be needed if there was no wind therefore the air will be still in the imaginary cylinder.

Comment: There would obviously be a temperature gradient from the wire to the six degree rise at the edge of the imaginary cylinder.There are eleven acres and initial cost of fans is $3000 per acre.Any coverings would be prohibitively expensive and difficult to install on seventeen thousand vines.  May eventually go with the sprinkler, but will have to buy $25,000 tank to store the water.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you can surround your 4-hectare field with [R-1 (SI units: 1 K-m<sup>2</sup>/W) insulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_%28insulation%29#Units) (e.g., approximately 1 inch of foam board insulation), top, bottom and sides. That's a total of 81600 m<sup>2</sup> of heat-transfer area. You want to raise the temperature by 6°F, which is 3.33 K, so the heat flux is over 270 kW.

You'll need almost 1200A @ 230V, or about 11A per row. That would be a resistance of 230/11 = about 21Ω per row. You could get this as a single strand of 3.6mm Nichrome (roughly AWG 7) or as, say, 8 strands of 1.27 mm copper (AWG 16).

Comment: That's a good way of looking at the problem, but it would be a good idea to put your R-1 insulation in perspective to either show how unrealistic it is or how difficult it would be to acheive. People are probably more familiar with "R" values in BTU / square foot / degF / hour, like is used when you buy insulation at Home Despot and the like.

Comment: Thinking about the insulation problem, if party foam bubbles could somehow be stabilized with something like cellulose, it could be sprayed into the vineyard before the freeze event. Would only need to be stable for a day then degrade.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for makes no sense just from a power point of view alone.  Do the math.

Just to pick something, let's start with very conservative wind of 1 mile/hour = 450 mm/s.  If the wire is supposed to heat a volume of air within 18 inches (460 mm), then each second for each meter of wire, it must bring a volume of 450mm x 460mm x 2 x 1m = 0.41 m<sup>3</sup> up to temperature (the factor of two is because the 18 inch range extends on both sides of the wire).

The density of air at 0°C is about 29 g/mole = 29g / 22.4l = 1.30 g/l = 1.3 kg/m<sup>3</sup>.  That times the 0.41 m<sup>3</sup> from above means 531 grams of air need to be heated per second.

The heat capacity of air at 0°C is 1 kJ/kg°C.  (1 kJ/kg°C) x (0.531 kg) x 3.3°C = 1.75 kJ.  That's how much energy 1 meter of wire needs to put out every second, or 3.19 kW, just to keep up with a 1 mile/hour wind.  You have over 21.4 km of wire that has to put out this much power, so that would take about 37.5 MW.

37.5 MW is clearly absurd, and that is only to deal with 1 mile/hour air movement.

Note that this has nothing to do with how exactly the air is heated, whether from a wire or something else.  That's the power the heater has to put out regardless of the mechanism.

As Dave Tweed pointed out in a comment, this calculation is assuming the wind sweeps away the warm air to where it is of no use anymore.  Some of the warm air will be pushed to neighboring grape vines, so the power isn't totally lost.  However, due to the fact that warm air is less dense, this warm air will generally rise.  This will cause turbulences and up and down drafts in unpredictable locations as the warm air rises and cold air from above falls to replace it.

The exact behaviour is impossible to predict, but that hardly matters here.  Remember that this calculation was based on a very slight wind.  Even if somehow 3/4 of the heated air stays within the grape height per second, that still requires 9.4 MW heating power, which again, was only for a 1 mile/hour wind.

Comment: You mixed up C and F. Plus, you have your "wind" blowing directly up or down through the vineyard, not across it. See my answer, which is based on heat flux through a surface that surrounds the vineyard.

Comment: @Dave: Fixed the C versus F error.  I added a comment about warm air getting re-used, but I still don't see this making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Lets pick a Nichrome wire and work through this.  The problem is going to be that most wire has data related to heat starting at around 400°C.  So data down in the lower temperature regions is hard to predict.

26 AWG Nichrome

2.67 \$\Omega/ft\$

400°C at 1.58 A

650 ft x 2.67 \$\Omega/ft\$ = 1735.5 \$\Omega\$ \$^1\$

Max current is 220V / 1735.5 \$\Omega\$ = 0.127 A.

108 rows is 13.7 A of power.  Not completely out of the realm of possibility.  It could get warm.  It would make your power meter spin, but maybe.

I would hate to have to purchase 650 ft x 108 rows = 13.3 MILES of nichrome wire.  Probably not the least expensive thing to buy.

Now the practical issues.  If you were to tent over all your grapes, there is a possibility of the heat staying within 18" of the wire.  Otherwise, the air will heat up and lift into the sky as cold air replaces it.  This is general convection.

I would guess that tenting with some other type of heated air blown solution makes a whole lot more sense than just stringing a wire.  It may be possible, but it just doesn't seem like a good solution.

\$^1\$ I excluded the resistance of the return wire.  It would make most sense to use nichrome to return and actually use a 1300ft run, so the resistance in the return wire is at least useful.

Comment: The only available alternative would be 13 miles of pulsating sprinklers and a twenty thousand gallon tank. A lot of expense for use six hours every four years.  What about filling vineyard with 45 inch deep cellulose stabilized party foam for insulation?

Answer (score 0):

Canopy solutions for over 12 miles of vines is not trivial but effective with gas fired hot air blowers.

Electric heaters require significant power but may be beneficial to heating water conduit lines with controls..

Machine pruning lowers risk of frost damage if no buds yet.

Micromist sprayer Sprinkler solutions offer best economical solutions but must ensure heat absorption by freezing water exceeds heat loss by evaporation. Wind blowers may include helicopters.

> Low dew point can further exacerbate this problem. To avoid damage
>   under these conditions, sprinklers should be started at 1.1°C (34°F)
>   if the dew point is -4.4°C (24°F) or above; 1.7°C (35°F) if the dew
>   point is -6.7 to -5.0°C (20-23°F); and 2.2°C (36°F) if the dew point
>   is -9.4 to -7.2°C (15-19°F). This recommendation should only be
>   followed when a frost is predicted. Sprinklers may be turned off when
>   the air temperature has risen to 1.1°C (34°F).